# Mathjax/Matplotlib font in Jupyter

Tags: matplotlib, fonts, jupyter

I'm making a plot using Matplotlib in Jupyter.  The issue I'm having is that Mathjax renders math font using the default Maplotlib font (Dejavu Sans, I believe).  I want to use Times New Roman, so this issue makes my plot have two different fonts.  I've included a short example that highlights the issue I'm having with Jupyter and Matplotlib (Also, to give proper reference, I used the code from [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/simple_plot.html) and just added a couple of lines).

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
plt.plot(t, s)

plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'Times New Roman'

plt.xlabel('See, this is in Times New Roman 12345')
plt.ylabel(r'$but-this-is-not-12345$')
plt.title(r'This has both Times New Roman $and-Mathjax$')
plt.grid(True)
plt.savefig("test.png")
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot with two fonts]

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken this has nothing at all to do with MathJax; it's the TeX-rendering code in Matplotlib. MathJax renders math in HTML. Could you please edit your question? It's misleading as it is written. (I happen to be looking for how to configure MathJax in Jupyter.)

Comment: I had proposed editing the title to "How to change matplotlib mathtext font to Times New Roman" and a few small edits to remove references to Mathjax, but they were rejected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these settings in addition to the one you already have:
`plt.rcParams['mathtext.default'] = 'rm'`
`plt.rcParams['mathtext.fontset'] = 'stix'`